# Is there a way to configure the neo4j-shell to echo commands

Tags: neo4j

I have some ETL code that sometimes takes awhile to run. I'd just like to know what's running. When I run

```
neo4j-shell -file mycode.cql
```

Is there a way to see either

1. An "echo" of the cypher being run as it is loaded, or
2. Just some random text, without doing something, er, hacky, e.g.

   MATCH () RETURN "Frobnibbles loaded!" LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 1):

No echo unfortunately, but you can just use `return` (you don't need the MATCH or LIMIT bit):

```
return "Hello, world!";
```